# Stage Builder, do you get more parts?

Tags: wii-u, super-smash-bros-4

It doesn't look like the stage builder has very many *moving parts*. It's quite cool that you can draw the stage, but I miss a lot of the pieces available in the *Brawl* version.

Can you/How do you unlock new parts for the stage builder in Super Smash Bros. WiiU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing more to unlock via the stage builder. With any luck, Nintendo will add content in subsequent updates.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, so far it seems like you can't. The stage builder seemed like such a cool idea, but the fact that drawing anything precise is impossible, it's incredibly difficult to place grabbable edges, and lack of obstacles/moving parts kind of let me down. I'm sure someone more creative than I can utilize it better, but I really hope they release an update with fixes for edge grabbing, more parts, and decorations or something.

Comment: You can draw precisely! At any time in the stage editor, press X to toggle a grid that lets you draw straight lines. You can also tap individual points on the grid, and the stage editor will automatically draw straight lines between them.(This also makes it easier to draw grabbable edges.)